# Using AngularJS, which is optimal with regards to ng-repeat

Tags: performance, web-applications, mobile, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a potentially long repeating list with lots of data associated with each reapeated list element. There is also a hidden panel that contains more data and interactive tools that can be used on each repeated element (comments, tags, etc.).

**My question is:** Is it more efficient to include a duplicate of this panel within each ng-repeat, already filled with the appropriate data, or have one panel outside of the ng-repeat scope, who's data get's fill after clicking the 'panel toggle' button?

*Extra details:* This is a responsive site, with an emphasis on mobile use, so we are trying to minimize data sent, and make the amount of Javascript short and sweet (so far it hasn't been a problem at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After typing it out, I think the best option would be to have one tools panel, and populate it depending on which 'panel toggle' button is clicked. Fewer DOM elements the better, right?

It also leave it open for lazy-loading of the extra details in the future.